# What is the diffrent about write or not suspendCoroutine/resume in suspend function

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

What is the diffrent about below function.

```
suspend fun doSomething1():Boolean{
  val res = longtimeFunction()
  return res
}
```

```
suspend fun doSomething2():Boolean = suspendCoroutine{ continuation->
  val res = longtimeFunction()
  continuation.resume(res)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference because this is not how you use `suspendCoroutine`. In order to achieve the suspending, non-blocking behavior, first you need an API that doesn't perform blocking calls and instead has a method that starts an operation and returns immediately, but takes a *callback* from you that will be notified of the result. For example:

```
suspend fun doSomething2() = suspendCoroutine<Boolean> { continuation ->
    asyncLongtimeFunction(object: Callback {
        override fun onSuccess(res: Boolean) {
           continuation.resume(res)
        }
    })
}
```